# bash script to check file name begins with expected string

Tags: bash, if-statement, pattern-matching, string-matching

Running on OS X with a bash script:

```
sourceFile=`basename $1`
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "$sourceFile" =~ "adUsers.txt" ]]; then echo success ; else echo fail ; fi
```

The above works, but what if the user sources a file called `adUsers_new.txt`?

I tried:

```
if [[ "$sourceFile" =~ "adUsers*.txt" ]]; then echo success ; else echo fail ; fi
```

But the wildcard doesn't work in this case.
I'm writing this script to allow for the user to have different iterations of the source file name, which must begin with `aduser` and have the `.txt` file extension.

Comment: I believe you need to not quote the RHS of the `=~` operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash`, you can get the first seven characters of a shell variable with:

```
${sourceFile:0:7}
```

and the last four with:

```
${sourceFile:${#sourceFile}-4}
```

Armed with that knowledge, simply use those expressions where you would normally use the variable itself, something like the following script:

```
arg=$1
shopt -s nocasematch
i7f4="${arg:0:7}${arg:${#arg}-4}"
if [[ "${i7f4}" = "adusers.txt" ]] ; then
    echo Okay
else
    echo Bad
fi
```

You can see it in action with the following transcript:

```
pax> check.sh hello
Bad

pax> check.sh addUsers.txt
Bad

pax> check.sh adUsers.txt
Okay

pax> check.sh adUsers_new.txt
Okay

pax> check.sh aDuSeRs_stragngeCase.pdf.gx..txt
Okay
```

Comment: That works undoubtedly. But why? Why not just use wildcard matching?

Answer (score 6):

`=~` operator requires regexp, not wildcard. `==` accepts wildcards, but they should not be quoted:

```
if [[ "$sourceFile" == adUsers*.txt ]]; then echo success; else echo fail; fi
```

You may use a regexp too of course, but it would be a bit overkill:

```
if [[ "$sourceFile" =~ ^adUsers.*\.txt$ ]]; then echo success; else echo fail; fi
```

Please note that regexp is open by default (`a` == `.*a.*`) while glob is closed (`a` != `*a*`).

Comment: The RegEx makes it applicable to more situations